# rails passing params to view after redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I want to pass 2 strings to the view after redirecting.
the controller:

```
def create
    @rating = Rating.new(params[:rating])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rating.save
        format.html { redirect_to @rating, :notice => 'Got It!' ,
                      :notice_small => 'Your photo has been uploaded. good luck with it\'s coolness rating!' }
        format.json { render :json => @rating, :status => :created, :location => @rating }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.json { render :json => @rating.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

the view:

```
<p id="notice" class="big_notice"><%= notice %></p>

<% if defined? notice_small  %>
    <p id="small_notice" class="small_notice"><%= notice_small %></p>
<% end %>
```

the notice string goes throw but the notice_small does not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only `:notice` and `:alert` are allowed to be set using `redirect_to`.

If you want something beyond this, use `:flash => { :notice_small => '....' }` option for `redirect_to` or set `flash[:notice_small]` before `redirect_to` explicitly.

Comment: how do i access this in the view?

Comment: Your `notice` is just a shortcut for `flash.notice` which is in its turn calls `flash[:notice]`. So you can access both `:notice` and `:notice_small` via `flash[:...]`.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect looks like it should work as far as I can tell.  However, to make it available in your view, the action you're redirecting to would have to take `params["notice_small"]` and put it in an instance variable. Something like

```
@notice_small = params["notice_small"]
```

in the actions, then you could do

```
<% if defined? @notice_small  %>
    <p id="small_notice" class="small_notice"><%= @notice_small %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: hi scott, thanks for the quick response. but it still didn't work with  `@notice_small = 'Your photo has been uploaded. good luck with its coolness rating!'` and changing (in the view) from `notice_small` to `@notice_small`

Comment: Can you add your ruby/rails versions and the action that you're redirecting to?